Firebase console server key is disabled and leading to error message on Google Cloud Page
I am trying to generate server key for notification on firebase console, but as I click on "Manage API on Google Console" from the right option, then  it leads to google cloud page with an error message.
There was an error while loading /apis/library/googlecloudmessaging.googleapis.com?authuser=4&project=abc-b896e&hl=en. Please try again.
It may be a browser or network issue. Go to the loading issues help page  to troubleshoot the issue.

I tried with service account's permission set to Owner, Editor but nothing works.

Sending messages with a server key has been deprecated, and will soon stop working altogether. Use the versioned API instead as explained here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1

Also posted on https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/1cx3rcw/cannot_retrieve_server_key_in_cloud_messaging_tab/

I believe the issue lies with the "Cloud Messaging API (Legacy)." We received notification to migrate to the "Firebase Cloud Messaging API (V1)," as the legacy version will be deprecated by June 20, 2024. After this date, we will no longer have access to the library.
